# Is there a solution for the "cannot import name 'build_dataset' from 'mmseg.datasets'" error?

Tags: python, importerror, semantic-segmentation

I run the following code on GitHub and get the following error. Can anyone give us a solution?

`ImportError: cannot import name 'build_dataset' from 'mmseg.datasets' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmseg/datasets/__init__.py)`

https://github.com/rstrudel/segmenter/blob/master/README.md#installation

This is despite the fact that I had run these codes a few days ago without errors . I have searched a lot on the internet and have not found any results.

Comment: please file an issue on that github repository

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.